# Show that End$(R,+) \cong$End$(R,+,\cdot)$ if for each $f\in$End$(R,+)$ and each $x\in R$ holds $f(x)=f(1)x$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a ring with identity and $(\mathbb{End}(R,+),+,\circ)$ be the correspondent ring of endomorphisms. I want to show that Show that End$(R,+) \cong$End$(R,+,\cdot)$ (seen as rings) if for each $f\in$End$(R,+)$ and each $x\in R$ holds $f(x)=f(1)x$.

What I tried is to take the function $\phi:\mathbb{End}(R,+)\to\mathbb{End}(R,+,\cdot)$ defined by $\phi(f)=f$. Clearly it satisfies $\phi(f+g)=\phi(f)+\phi(g), \phi(fg)=\phi(f)\phi(g)$ and that $\phi(1)=1$ but how do I prove that $\phi(f)$ in fact is an endomorphism of rings of $R$? Clearly it satisfies $\phi(f)(a+b)=\phi(f)(a)+\phi(f)(b)$, but for multiplication I only get that $f(ab)=f(1)ab$ and that $f(a)f(b)=f(1)af(1)b$ so I can't conclude that $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ or maybe I'm defining wrong my $\phi$.

Comment: MathJax tip: If you want to use a custom mathematics operator, like $\operatorname{End}$, use `\operatorname{End}`, rather than just moving in and out of maths mode. Text mode makes "End" looks slightly different, plus spacing can be tricky. Compare `$f \in \operatorname{End}(R, +)$`, which produces $f \in \operatorname{End}(R, +)$, with `$f \in$End$(R, +)$`, which produces $f \in$End$(R, +)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is false. Consider $R=(\mathbb Z,+,\cdot)$. Then every group endomorphism $f$ of $(\mathbb Z,+)$ is precisely a map satisfying $f(x)=f(1)x$ for all $x\in\mathbb Z$, that means precisely a multiplication-by-$a$ map. But for example, the multiplication-by-$2$ map $m_2$ is not a ring endomorphism of $(\mathbb Z,+,\cdot)$, which can be seen by $8=2\cdot4=m_2(4)=m_2(2\cdot2)\ne m_2(2)m_2(2)=4\cdot4=16$. In fact, there is only one ring endomorphism of $\mathbb Z$, namely the identity map. This can be seen by $g(x)=g(1)x=x$ because of $g(1)=1$ for every ring endomorphism $g$ of $\mathbb Z$.

So $(\operatorname{End}(\mathbb Z,+),+)\cong (\mathbb Z,+)$ and also $(\operatorname{End}(\mathbb Z,+),+,\circ)\cong (\mathbb Z,+,\cdot)$, but $(\operatorname{End}(\mathbb Z,+,\cdot),+)$ is the trivial group and $(\operatorname{End}(\mathbb Z,+,\cdot),+,\circ)$ the trivial ring.